# Android espresso error no tests found

Tags: android, android-espresso

I try to use Espresso test framework for testing my app.

Env:

Android Studio RC1 (from canary)
Latest Android Gradle plugin, 0.14+

I added as described here (https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso#Getting_Started)

```
dependencies {
    //espresso - test framework

    androidTestCompile files('libs/espresso-1.1.jar',
            'libs/testrunner-1.1.jar',
            'libs/testrunner-runtime-1.1.jar')

    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1',
            'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
}

 packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

defaultConfig {
        //espresso - test framework
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
```

Also I created simple test:

```
public class StartActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<StartActivity> {
    public StartActivityTest(Class<StartActivity> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        // Espresso will not launch our activity for us, we must launch it via getActivity().
        getActivity();
    }

    public void testStartVisibility() {
        onView(withId(R.id.app_title))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));

        onView(withId(R.id.app_thumb))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));

        onView(withId(R.id.label))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed())
                );

        onView(withId(R.id.label)).check(matches(withText("Hello Espresso!")));
    }

}
```

But i get an error:

```
com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > hasTests[Nexus 5 - 5.0] FAILED 
No tests found.                           
:app:connectedAndroidTest FAILED          

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

[image: See screenshot for detailes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

I have to use default constructor as below:

```
public StartActivityTest() {
    super(StartActivity.class);
}
```

That fixed problem.

Comment: I've got the same thing but still have 'No tests found'

Comment: Did you see my build.gradle above? Please check that ypu use GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner instead default